# Upgraded MongoDb to 3.4.3 but mongod --version still shows 3.2.1

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have upgraded my MongoDB community version to 3.4.3

When i run `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

i get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mongodb-org is already the newest version (3.4.3).
```

but when i run `mongod --version`

i get

```
db version v3.2.11
git version: 009580ad490190ba33d1c6253ebd8d91808923e4
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1604
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

***Edit***

I ran `apt-file list mongodb-server` and I got
[image: result]

***Update(Temp Solution)***

I decided to download v3.4.3 binaries using tarball

```
mkdir ~/bin && cd ~/bin
curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.3.tgz
tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.3.tgz
mv ./mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.3 ./mongodb
rm mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.3.tgz
```

updated the `mongod.service` file by replacing `/usr/bin/mongod` to `~/bin/mongodb/bin/mongod`

reloaded the `systemctl` daemon and restarted the service

Comment: It must be several versions of mongodb installed in the system. Check `which mongod` returns the same path as `apt-file list mongodb-org` does.

Comment: I don't get anything when I run `apt-file list mongodb-org`

Answer (score 1):

i think this isn't a oficial solution, but i did have the same problem yesterday, and i solved this running this

1. `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb` ( this go back to the db version v2.6.10 )
2. `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` ( and this really install db version v3.4.3 )

and restart the service (sudo service mongod restart)

i hope this can help you!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check your `sources.list`s where you get `mongodb-server` from. The official package `mongodb-org` should be from `http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse`.

Backup your configs, and force reinstall: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y mongodb-org`

Comment: i checked and it has correct path. I ended up downloading the tar file of 3.4.3 binaries and pointed my `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` to the new mongod executable